# Hibernate and querying a view. Result count is OK, but all rows are the same but they aren't on the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity representing a view on the (mysql) database:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "user_info_view")
public class UserInfoView implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_uuid")
    private String userUUID;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    //getters, setters, constructors...

    }
```

The view is created using a simple SQL, like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW USER_INFO_VIEW
AS
    SELECT u.USER_UUID,
           u.NAME,
           a.ADDRESS
    FROM
    USER u
    JOIN
    ADDRESS a
    ON a.ID = u.ADDRESS_ID
```

And a repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserInfoViewRepository extends JpaRepository<UserInfoView, String> {

    List<UserInfoView> findAllByUserUUID(String userUUID);
    
}
```

`SELECT * FROM USER_INFO_VIEW` is returning 4 rows. Running `findAllByUserUUID()` method returns a list of 4 `UserInfoView` objects, but they are all the same - and they contain data from the first row in the database.

Here are the results of queries on the database:

SELECT * FROM USER:

```
id | user_uuid | name | address_id |
------------------------------------
1  | UUID1     | john | 1          |
2  | UUID1     | jane | 2          |
3  | UUID1     | josh | 3          |
4  | UUID1     | mark | 4          |
------------------------------------ 

SELECT * FROM ADDRESS:

id | address            | name  | is_current |
----------------------------------------------
1  | some address 1     | addr1 | 1          |
2  | some address 2     | addr2 | 0          |
3  | some address 3     | addr3 | 1          |
4  | some address 4     | addr4 | 1          |
---------------------------------------------- 

SELECT * FROM USER_VIEW WHERE USER_UUID = "UUID1":

user_uuid | name | address            |
---------------------------------------
UUID1     | john | some address 1     |
UUID1     | jane | some address 2     |
UUID1     | josh | some address 3     |
UUID1     | mark | some address 4     |
---------------------------------------
```

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: can you provide information about the rows which you are trying to join in these two tables?

Comment: What is the result when you execute the query in your `database`?

Comment: @NoraNa I am not sure if I understand Your question - what information do You need me to provide? What data is in those rows? What data types I use?

Comment: @HarryCoder the result from a query in the database is correct - I get 4 rows I mentioned, but they all contain different sets of data, and all this data is consistent with both tables

Comment: I mean the rows in your user and address tables.

Comment: @NoraNa I have added the query results from the DB.

Do not take the data model too seriously, cause it is just an example ;)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the `user_uuid` column is not unique causes the duplicates since it's marked as @Id and JPA uses its value to find the entities. You'll need a [composite PK](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-composite-primary-keys) using either an `IdClass` or an `EmbeddedId` containing the identifiying attributes.